# count multiple values in multiple column PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to count multiple values from 3 columns and sorted descending using PHP mysqli, and I can't do it.

| name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mike | jack | rose |
| jack | mike | Mary |
| jack | Mary | John |

expect output:

```
jack 3 
mike 2
mary 2
rose 1
John 1
```

My code:

```
$query = "select count(*) as c from work" ;
$result = $con->query($query);
$count = $result->fetch_object()->c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION` to get them all into a single column. Then use `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`:

```
$query = "
SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM (
    SELECT name1 AS name
    FROM work
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name2 AS name
    FROM work
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name3 AS name
    FROM work
) AS x
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY c DESC";
$result = $con->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    echo "$row->name $row->c<br>";
}
```

Comment: could you write the fetch code cause it doesn't work for me

Comment: I added the fetch loop.

Comment: finally, thanks a lot!